# Dual booting Ubuntu and windows 10 on Baytrail /2 gb /32 gb eMMC device

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, emmc, intel-atom

I have a Baytrail netbook with 2gb Ram and 32 gb eMMC storage comes with windows 10 32 bit preloaded .But i want to have an Ubuntu based 64 bit distro along with the default OS . I can't completely replace it with Ubuntu since specs doesn't allow 64 bit ubuntu to run smoothly as like win 10 (32bit ) does and manufacturer only support OS that comes preinstalled . How can i overcome the storage space , performance issue ? and help me to choose the correct Ubuntu flavor .

Comment: "and help me to choose the correct Ubuntu flavor "  We only have 1 base system and different desktops. But what to pick is entirely up to you. "How can i overcome the storage space , performance issue ?" Eh you can't. It will be slow. Period. Worse in storage space even as you share it with another OS where most will have an Ubuntu and no Windows.

Comment: @Rinzwind so all Ubuntu flavors need same amount of resources because they have same base system.

Comment: ... with slight differences in the desktop and initially installed services. But basically yes, all official Ubuntu use the same core. The "server" edition is the core and all flavours put their desktop onto that. With 2Gb you are likely to use a server so ... no differences there.